# Show where an episode ends with a man levitating, imprisoned in a top secret facility?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv, episode-identification

I watched the show in the 90s *possibly* early 00s, and it didn't seem like it could have been made any earlier than the late 80s.

The show was part of an episodic mystery show like Outer Limits or Twilight Zone, or possibly X-Files? I've tried to look for the episode amongst that back catalog, but so far no joy. In this episode I think a man had been abducted by, or had been accused of associating with aliens in some way?

The point of the episode was, until the last scene, it was never confirmed if he had actually interacted with aliens, or any of his claims of going beyond human limitations were true.

The episode closes on him speaking through a window on the secure door to a military personnel, disagreeing over the nature of his imprisonment. Then the scene cuts to *inside* his cell, and he's actually levitating.

What was the show and episode I am trying to remember?

Comment: This sounds like the Showtime 1995 Outer Limits reboot which seemed like every other show was aliens and military,  alternating in with weird science gone bad.

Comment: @SillybutTrue thats what I thought, but when I went looking, I couldn't find the episode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this was *[The Visitor](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118509/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_65)*, a very promising show that was, unfortunately, cancelled in the middle of the pilot season.

The scene in question is the ending of the first episode (S1E1, but it's the second episode chronologically, after the Pilot S1E0) - *Fear of Flying*.
It is not involving the MC - imprisoned man is a scientist whom the protagonist had shown how to do that.

Comment: It is definitly that show. The first episide "Fear of flying" ends that way.

Comment: The Visitor, episode 1, the fear of flying: "He finds help from a high school science teacher/inventor trying to perfect anti gravity." Episode 9, "Caged" - "The FBI finally catches up to Adam and takes him to a federal prison for questioning." Episode 10,  "Going home" - "After his escape from the FBI, Adam must get..." . So, episode 2, he gets antigravity device. In episode 9 he is captured. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118509/episodes?ref_=tt_eps_sm